# Checking for different characters in C

Tags: c, char, c-strings, kernighan-and-ritchie

I wanted to know if there is a way in c to check, for example in a for function if a variable is equal or unequal to certain characters without having to repeat each time an equality check.
If I am not wrong, checking equality this way is incorrect:

```
if (a == ('\n' || '\t' || ' ' || ',' || '.' || ';' || ':' || '!' || '?')) {
     execute certain action;
}
```

you would need to have an endless chain of `a == '\n' || a == '\t' || ...`. I was wondering if there was a shorter (and cleaner) way to check equality for a list of symbols, because when instead of `a` you have something more descriptive, this code becomes a mess. 
Also, if you could explain to me why the first part is wrong, I would be grateful.

Comment: See `isspace()`, `ispunc()`, etc, in ctype.h.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `strchr()` to search for the character in a string.

```
#include <string.h>

if (strchr("\n\t ,.;:!?", a) != NULL) {
    // execute certain action
}
```

The reason why your attempt doesn't work is because the `||` operator is combining all its operands using the boolean `OR` operation, and returns a boolean value. `x || y` is true if either `x` or `y` is non-zero. So your test is essentially equivalent to

```
if (a == 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just write a function similar to the following

```
#include <string.h>

//...

int is_separatison( char c )
{
    const char *s = "n\t ,.;:!?";

    return c != '\0' && strchr( s, c ) != NULL;
}
```

The same expression you can use in an if statement. Only you can remove the comparison with the zero character if you know that the checked character is not a zero character.

```
const char *s = "n\t ,.;:!?";

if ( strchr( s, c ) != NULL )
{
    // do something
}
```

As for showed by you if statement then it shall be rewritten like

```
if ( a == '\n' || a == '\t' || a == ' ' || a == ',' || 
     a == '.'  || a ==';'   || a == ':' || a == '!' || a == '?' )  {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`strchr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) function, which checks for the first occurrence of a character in a given string (which can be a string literal). If it's *not* found, the function returns a `NULL` (zero) value.

So, in your case, you could do this:

```c
if (strchr("\n\t ,.;:!?", a) == NULL) {
    // Action when NOT found
}
else {
    // Action when found
}
```

(You need to `#include <string.h>` somewhere in your source to use this function.)